# Embedding Image with a source pathway which needs to change ....?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Well, I like to find out if it could be possible to use this normal type Embed code, and say have a pathway which is changing by selecting different Images in the Application with text from an Imput-Text field ??? without recompiling ???
Or better I say is it at all possible to Embed an Image once the App. is run ???

Any help would be appreciated on this! regards aktell

```
<code>  
    [Embed(source="../assets/sample.jpg")]
    protected var jpgBytes:Class;
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

no.

that will embed the asset into the swf and therefore will always need to be recompiled if the asset changes.

you would have to load the image as external asset to be able to change it in run time. if the path needs to change too, you will need to have that as an external data source also.